# lock answering for questions for a short time

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)
>   [Don’t show the answers for the question in the first 2 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6917/dont-show-the-answers-for-the-question-in-the-first-2-minutes)
>   [Is the fastest gun in the west solved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved)

I often see the following pattern on SO:

- question newly created
- user *A* thinks *"oh, have a rough idea on that, have to be fast for rep"*
- user *B* thinks *"hm, lets not be too quick and give a good answer"*
- user *A* quickly adds a very short and low quality answer

In short, often answers seem to be hurried, probably because people want the reputation by being first because most users sort by *oldest* for voting.

This often leads to some obscure behaviours like:

- user *B* still adds a 'better' answer but user *A* edits fast enough and still gets the upvotes
- or user *B* doesn't add his better answer as *"user A will probably edit soon"*, user *A* doesn't edit as he is already getting upvotes and thinks *"my answer seems to be good enough"*
- or users don't think about adding better answers if there are already some answers present, especially if they are by high-rep users

To summarize, i often think answer quality could be better if there was a short lock on answering (e.g. 1 minute) to avoid quick shots. Would that make sense?

*(Not that i'm sure about this, but i think there might be ways to improve the average answer quality)*

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6917/dont-show-the-answers-for-the-question-in-the-first-2-minutes

Comment: Brandon, the question is about not displaying answers immediately while i was thinking about not letting users submit answers immediately... but i guess the accepted answer might be what i was looking for.

Comment: The Fastest Gun in the West is by design. It's designed so that you can fire off something quickly, then edit it into shape. Sadly, some users skip over the second step there.