# Holding time for new answers to curb "simple+quick then improve over time"

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Don't show the answers for the question in the first 2 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6917/dont-show-the-answers-for-the-question-in-the-first-2-minutes)

I believe that there should be a feature implemented so that no new answers are shown until 5-10 minutes after the question has been posted.

I believe this will stop people providing low-quality, simple answers to get in quick and get up-votes and rather encourage them to take time to answer the question, add demos on the likes of JSFiddle etc and fully read the users question.

As I among others feel that the current answering scheme means that the only option to answer and get rep that merits the quality answer given is to get in quick and then build upon the answer, which I believe is wrong.

This current scheme is degrading the quality of our communities answers and will give newer "non-savvy" SO users a chance to earn rep for well put-together questions.

**UPDATE**

User @Loktar had a great idea in SO chat:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/326799#326799

> Make it to where a user chooses if it has a delay, and any question that has a delay gives a bonus +5 rep

Thus meaning it is opt-in and the user is happy with a slight delay for a better quality answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Don't show the answers for the question in the first 2 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6917/dont-show-the-answers-for-the-question-in-the-first-2-minutes) (and, of course, the venerable [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the only option to answer in order to get rep

Surely the reason you answer is to help your fellow programmers struggling alone or in a cubicle in their freezing or sweltering flat or office, working with inadequate tools on inadequate computers for inadequate pay, being unappreciated by their managers.

Comment: You misread my question, in order to get rep (for the ability to down-vote and up-vote for example) for new users is very important as it means they can do more with the site, I'm not saying people answer just to get rep, I did not punctuate the question correctly.

Comment: @Myles - I hoped that a) my convoluted sentence structure and b) the fact I marked this as CW would indicate I wasn't being totally serious ;)

Comment: Not exactly that SO savvy myself yet, missed that it was cw ;)  Check the above amended question for a more user friendly option